# Xcode 7.2.1 Swift 2 - Updating to Xcode 7.3

Tags: swift, xcode7.3

As I'm getting this "Could not find Developer Disk Image" error when trying to run my app on my iPhone 6s, I notice that most people are suggesting to upgrade to Xcode 7.3.

My iPhone 6s is running iOS 9.2. I have Xcode 7.2.1 and my Mac version is El Capitan 10.11.

I want to download Xcode 7.3 from here https://developer.apple.com/downloads/

My question is, do I have to uninstall Xcode 7.2.1 first or can I just run the new Xcode 7.3 file and would it take care of upgrading the current Xcode version to new? Do I have to take a backup of my app projects before doing anything? Right now my projects are in Desktop.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: update your iPhone version

Comment: Thanks @ÖzgürErsil. So I should update it to 9.3 from 9.2? What about my Xcode 7.2.1 would it support iOS 9.3?

Comment: you can keep different versions of Xcode at the same time

Comment: you mean I can have two Xcode installations? I can open the same project in either one Xcode? I thought the system would not allow another version of Xcode to run while an older version exists?

Comment: @ÖzgürErsil Thanks. I installed Xcode 7.3 and kept Xcode 7.2.1 and it worked fine. I noticed though, my simulator is a bit slow. Can I remove Xcode 7.2.1?

Answer (score 2):

I did it last month, I uninstalled XCode 7.2 first.  Then I launched the 7.3 file and XCode works. I don't think that the XCode 7.3 .dmg will upgrade your current XCode, because it's the entire software. Not an update.

You don't have to do a back up of your projects.  only XCode will be uninstalled. Your projects are where you have saved them.

Comment: Thank you. What's the best way to uninstall Xcode 7. I read many others that its not just a drag and drop into the Trash bin.

Comment: That's what I did. But if you really want to uninstall XCode properly, download appzapper for mac OS. This app removes all files in relation with the app you want to delete (except your projects obviously) - but I don't think it's really necessary, I didn't get any problems with drag'n drop into the trash bin.

Comment: I'll give it a try. Thanks.